# ruby nested for loops

Tags: ruby, for-loop

This might be a stupid question, but I am attempting to learn the basic's of Ruby so please be gentle. I would like to iterate thru an array of strings and then thru each letter in that string.

```
groceries = ['turkey', 'cranberries', 'stuffing', 'pumkin pie', 'whip-cream']

for i in groceries do
    p i
    for x in i do
        p x
    end
end
```

When I attempt to run this I get the following error. Any assistance would be awesome.

```
undefined method `each' for "turkey":String (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: I have, I have also gone thru stack overflow as well. As you can see from my points I'm not a first time poster or searcher

Comment: Firstly, `for` isn't really used in Ruby, use `groceries.each do |i| ... end ` instead (that's what's happening under the covers anyway, hence the error message). Then look up the methods on [`String`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-each_char).

Comment: Thank you @muistooshort!

Comment: `for x in i` isn't doing what you think. What you really want to do here is split your String into an Array of characters within your inner loop. There's more than one way to do that, but until you have an Enumerator of some sort (like an Array) you can't call #each on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using Array#map and String#each_char

For-loops are syntactic sugar in Ruby, and you generally won't see them in idiomatic Ruby code. Instead, Rubyists tend to use iterator methods. The following is more idiomatic, although there are certainly other ways to do what you are looking to accomplish.

```
groceries.map { |item| p item; item.each_char { |char| p char } }
```

In addition to printing the output you wanted, this has the benefit of returning your original Array of String values as well:

```
#=> ["turkey", "cranberries", "stuffing", "pumkin pie", "whip-cream"]
```

This works on any version of Ruby >= 2.7.1 (possibly earlier, but I didn't bother to test). You may be able to take further shortcuts using features from later Ruby versions, but this should certainly get you started.

Answer (score 2):

As [mu is too short said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69978728/ruby-nested-for-loops#comment123702417_69978728) `each` seems to be more aligned with standard Ruby convention.  That said, I'm a novice with Ruby and programming in general.  So take my opinions with a grain of salt.

At any rate, there are a few useful methods that seem to fit your need.  `each_char` and `chars` will iterate through a string.

```
for i in groceries do
  p i
    i.chars { |c| p c }
end
```

Or,

```
groceries.each do |i|
  p i
  i.chars { |c| p c }
end
```

Comment: Passing a block to `chars` is deprecated. You should use `each_char { … }` instead. (which also reads better)

Comment: @Stefan I know the documentation says deprecated, but it still works as of 3.0.2, and I haven't seen anything that says it's going away with 3.1. Since it's sugar for `str.each_char.to_a` I wouldn't expect it to go away soon.